# Change jQuery Datatables dynamically

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a need to change a DataTable on the fly.

When the page is loaded the DataTable is loaded, then I check a value of the model and based of this I will either hide or show the `<table>`. However, the *Showing X of XX* and the *page* still show up.

- Is there any way to hide these?
- Also on the page I have a `checkbox` to either show or hide the table.  How do I do that dynamically?  I tried the *info* route but that either didn't work, or I got a can't reinitialize table error.

My table is:

```
$("#tblSelectedUserRoles").dataTable({
  sAjaxSource: '@Url.Action("GetAllStepsUser")?' + "userId=" + $("#txtSelectedUserId").val(),
  bJQueryUI: true,
  dom: 'T<"clear">rtip',
  bAutoWidth: false,
  "aoColumns": [{
    "sWidth": "1%",
    sClass: "smallFonts"
  }, {
    "sWidth": "1%",
    sClass: "smallFonts"
  }, {
    "sWidth": "14%",
    sClass: "smallFonts"
  }, {
    "sWidth": "40%",
    sClass: "smallFonts"
  }, {
    "sWidth": "20%",
    sClass: "smallFonts"
  }, {
    "sWidth": "15%",
    sClass: "smallFonts",
    "sName": "UserId",
    "mRender": function(data, type, row) {
      var chk = row[5] == 'True' ? ' checked="true" ' : ' ';
      var chk1;
      if (chk === ' ')
        chk1 = "false";
      else
        chk1 = "true";
      return "<input type='checkbox'" + chk + " id='chkuar" + row[0] + "' onchange=approved('" + row[0] + "','" + row[1] + "'," + chk1 + "); >";
    }
  }],
  tableTools: {
    "sSwfPath": "../../Scripts/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf", //'<c:url value="../../scripts/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"/>', //"//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf", // 
    "aButtons": [{
      "sExtends": "print",
      "bShowAll": true
    }]

  }
});
```

There is a checkbox where the onchange event calls this:

```
function changeStep() {
  var userId = $("#txtSelectedUserId").val();
  var val;
  if ($("#chkStep").is(':checked')) {
    val = 1;

    $("#tblSelectedUserRoles").show();
  } else {
    val = 0;

    $("#tblSelectedUserRoles").hide();
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      userId: userId,
      chk: val
    },
    url: '@Url.Action("UserStepAuthority")',
    success: function(data) {}
  });
}
```

Comment: Do you any code example?

Comment: You really need to show your code, what you are actually doing. We are not telepaths, sad but true - take for example the statement "_I tried the "info" route but that didn't work_" -  what would you guess yourself could make out of this, if you read something similar in another question, without further explanation? :)

Comment: @davidkonrad - added some code.  The problem is that when the checkbox is unset, the table hides just fine, but the "Showing" and "Page" line is still there.  How do you hide that?

Comment: @Dean.DePue - use  `$("#tblSelectedUserRoles_wrapper").hide()` instead - the table is along with the other injected controls placed in a wrapper, thats why the table is hidden but some of the controls still is visible. If you want to hide a dataTabled' table, hide the wrapper - not the table.

Comment: @davidkonrad - excellent!  That worked.  GIve me an answer so I can give your credit.  I did not know about the wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a `<table>` is dataTabled' it is in fact completely regenerated and placed inside a wrapper element, along with the other dataTables elements (such as pagination).

If you have a `<table id="example"></table>` then the resulting DOM layout will (by default) look like this :

```js
#example_wrapper
    #example_length     >   length menu
    #example_filter     >   search box
    #example            >   the table itself
    #example_info       >   table information
    #example_paginate   >   pagination buttons
```

So if you want to hide / show a dataTabled' `<table>`, then target the wrapper instead of the `<table>` itself :

```
$('#example_wrapper').hide();
```